# Ground states of the Hamiltonian of a two spin system

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-spin

For the spin system shown in this graph (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lg1R.png), the Hamiltonian is $$S^{(1)}_z\cdot S^{(1)}_z=\frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 &0  &0 \\ 
 0&-1  &0  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &-1  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  &1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The eigenvalues of this Hamiltonian are $-\frac{1}{4}$ when the eigenstate is $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
0 \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$$
or $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$$
and $\frac{1}{4}$ when the eigenstate is $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$$
or $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Moreover, the expectation value of the Hamiltonian for $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
0 \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$$
is $-\frac{1}{4}$ and for $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$$ is $\frac{1}{4}$.

Based on these information can we say that $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
0 \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$$ are the ground states of the Hamiltonian while $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$$ are the first excited states?

Comment: Note that whenever a state is an eigenstate of an observable, the expectation value of that observable in that state is always the eigenvalue. You don't need to specify that seperately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, but be aware that since the eigenvalues are degenerate, you have freedom of choice in defining a basis.  You might choose

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
0 \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
1 \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$

but someone else might like

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
{1 / \sqrt{2} }\\ 
{1 / \sqrt{2} } \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
{1 / \sqrt{2} } \\ 
-{1 / \sqrt{2} } \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I calculated expectation values of the basis states you mentioned for the same Hamiltonian, $\frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 &0  &0 \\ 
 0&-1  &0  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &-1  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  &1
\end{pmatrix}$. Can we say that $\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
{1 / \sqrt{2} }\\ 
{1 / \sqrt{2} } \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
{1 / \sqrt{2} } \\ 
-{1 / \sqrt{2} } \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$ are ground states as the expectation value is -0.25?

Comment: Moreover, $\begin{pmatrix}
{1 / \sqrt{2} } \\ 
0\\ 
0 \\ 
{1 / \sqrt{2} }
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
{1 / \sqrt{2} } \\ 
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
-{1 / \sqrt{2} }
\end{pmatrix}$ are first excited states as the expectation value is 0.25?